# Conditionally apply variable if data is present in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Probably simple answer for someone that knows JavaScript, I don't know it very well. I'm getting JSON data back and applying markers to a map. However it's generating markers for those that have null which really messes things up. So what I need to do is create a conditional variable based on data being present. I have the following in the code:

```
let mapElement = document.getElementById('map-banner');
let pointMarkers = mapElement.getAttribute('data-location');
let marked = JSON.parse(pointMarkers);
let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
console.log(pointMarkers);

marked.forEach(marked => {
  if (marked.lat > 0 && marked.lat !== null) {
      let lat = marked.lat;
  }
  let lng = marked.lng;

  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    map: map,
    icon: '/marker.png',
    title: marked.name
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.position);
});
map.fitBounds(bounds);
};
```

Specifically I'm working with the variables lat and lng. I've also tried:

```
let lat = marked.lat;
  if (lat > 0 && lat !== null) {
    const lat = marked.lat;
  }
```

In this case it presents all the data and it doesn't appear to be applying the condition.

Comment: um, you can not have `let` and `const` for same variable. You should drop the `const` and seems weird you do a check and than use same line inside... It is really unclear what the final outcome is supposed to be.

Comment: your `let lat = marked.lat;` lives only inside `if`, you need to put it outside: `let lat; if(...) {lat = marked.lat;}`

Comment: @espacarello different scopes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are conditionally declaring the variable, which for javascript is optional.
What you want is to skip that iteration in your loop with a guard clause:

```
marked.forEach(marked => {
    if (marked.lat == null)
        return;

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(marked.lat, marked.lng),
        map: map,
        icon: '/marker.png',
        title: marked.name
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @LudovitMydla pun intended?

Answer (score 2):

I think a filter is what you're looking for. Filtering can remove entries from arrays which you don't want to use.

Docs (by MDN) -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Also, const/let are used to achieve block scope in JavaScript.

consts are used for variables that do not change in value and are (preferably) immutable, see Docs -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

lets are used for values that do change in value, and have different values in different block scopes, see Docs -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

```
const mapElement = document.getElementById('map-banner');
const pointMarkers = mapElement.getAttribute('data-location');

// catch any error from JSON.parse
try {
    const coords = JSON.parse(pointMarkers);
    const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // filter out incorrect coords
    const markers = coords.filter(coord => {
        return (marked.lat > 0 && marked.lat !== null)  
    });

    // create markers, extend bounds
    markers.forEach(({ lat, lng }) => {
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map,
            icon: '/marker.png',
            title: marked.name
        }); 

        bounds.extend(marker.position);
    });

    // fit bounds
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
} catch (error) {
    // handle error to keep users happy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just show the marker if it exists?:

```
 if(marked.lat && marked.lat > 0) {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      map: map,
      icon: '/marker.png',
      title: marked.name
   });
}
```

Comment: This would also need to check for lng as well

Comment: @jake then do so.